# Avoid dividing by zero when doing numeric differentiation

Tags: scripting, numeric, numerical-methods

I'm current trying to find the derivative of a square wave type of function from raw data. Unfortunately the timescale of the function causes some divide by zero error. I know the source of this error isn't the code, but is the instrument recording the data, so in an ideal world I would use better tools, but is there any software workaround I would be able to use to at the very least approximate the slope?

Also, I'm using VBA to do this, and as far as I know there is no numeric differentiation function in vba, I'm currently just using the adjacent data entries to calculate slope [ie y'_x1 = (y_x2 - y_x0)/(x2 - x0)].

Comment: Could you post an example of  6-10 data points around some data point where you want to compute the derivative to demonstrate the quality of your data? Does VBA have statistical functions? Then you can use linear regression of such a neighborhood to compute a linear approximation where the slope is then an approximation of the derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular situation, I would advise to average `y` values that belong to the same `x` coordinate. Then, you will not have the issue of dividing by zero.